# Subtraction based on multiple groups in R

Tags: r

I have the following df and am looking to populate variable 3 which would be based off the Country and Branch and M1 of variable 1 divided by M1 - 1 of variable 2.

So for example, row 1 would give N/A since there is no M1 - 1, but for M2 the result for variable 3 would be 82/992 = 8.27%. What would be the best way on doing this?

I can think of creating another table which would move the Variable 2 to the month which needs to be subtracted and then merge with the current table using dplyr.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it?

```
Country Branch  Month   Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3
X       A       12      41          992         N/A
X       A       1       82          693         8.27%
X       A       2       40          686         5.77%
X       B       12      84          793         N/A
X       B       1       6           947         0.76%
X       B       2       48          809         5.07%
Y       A       12      78          546         N/A
Y       A       1       16          796         2.93%
Y       A       2       50          945         6.28%
Y       B       12      57          862         N/A
Y       B       1       73          689         8.47%
Y       B       2       1           971         0.15%
```

Comment: I think `df %>% group_by(Country, Branch) %>% mutate(v3 = v1 / lag(v2))`, but unable to test currently

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one as well just for the fun and practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Variable3 := as.character(round(100*Variable1/shift(Variable2), 2)), 
          by = .(Country, Branch)
           ][!is.na(Variable3), Variable3 := paste0(Variable3, "%")][]
```

Comment: This is amazing! I knew there must be a way to do it quicker